# JavaFX TableView not Updating UI

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I have a `Tableview<ObservableList<Item>>`, which is not updating when the underlying data is updated. Through debugging, I know that the underlying `ObservableList<Item>>` is being properly updated. I have ensured that all of `Item`'s properties are visible, and in the format `myFieldProperty()`.

Here is my table creation:

```
pattern= new TableView<>(mainApp.getItemList());

    for (ObservableList<Item> row : pattern.getItems()) {

        for (int i= pattern.getColumns().size(); i<row.size(); i++){
            final int columnIndex = i ;

            TableColumn<ObservableList<Item>, Color> column = new TableColumn<>();

            column.setCellValueFactory( rowData -> 
                    rowData.getValue()
                    .get(columnIndex).displayColorProperty()); // the Item for this cell

            column.setCellFactory(col -> {
                ItemCell cell = new ItemCell();

                cell.setOnMouseEntered( e -> {
                    if (cell.getItem() != null) {
                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        ObservableList<Item> stitchRow = 
                        (ObservableList<Item>) cell.getTableRow().getItem();
                        mainApp.getRLController().setItemLabel(itemRow.get(columnIndex).toString());
                    }
                });

                cell.setOnMouseExited( e -> {
                    mainApp.getRLController().setItemLabel(null);
                });

                cell.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
                    Item newItem = mainApp.getTBController().getSelectedItem();
                    if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY && newItem != null) {

                        ObservableList<Item> itemRow = 
                                (ObservableList<Item>) cell.getTableRow().getItem();
                        itemRow.set(columnIndex, newItem);  
                        mainApp.getRLController().setItemLabel(itemRow.get(columnIndex).toString());
                    }
                });

                return cell; 
                });

            column.setMinWidth(7);
            column.setPrefWidth(7);
            column.setMaxWidth(7);
            pattern.getColumns().add(column);
        }
    }
    pattern.setFixedCellSize(7);
    pattern.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);`
```

Code for my Custom Cell Factory:

```
public class ItemCell extends TableCell<ObservableList<Item>, Color> {

@Override 
protected void updateItem(Color color, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(color, empty); 

    if (empty || color == null) {
        setText(null);
        setStyle(null);
    } else {

        int r = (int) (color.getRed() * 255);
        int g = (int) (color.getGreen() * 255);
        int b = (int) (color.getBlue() * 255);

        this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ");" 
             + "-fx-border-color: black; -fx-table-cell-border-color: black;");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you changing the data? I mocked this up and it worked fine.

Comment: Through the cell.setOnMouseClicked() method. I replace an old item with a new Item that contains an ObjectProperty<Color>, and the color of the cell doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is that the object you are changing (the item which is an element of the list representing the row) is not the property that the cell is observing for changes (the `displayColorProperty()` belonging to the item). You need to arrange to change the value of a property that the cell is observing.

Three possible solutions:

If possible, just change the `displayColor` (and other data too) of the item displayed by the cell. I.e.

```
            cell.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
                if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY && newItem != null) {

                    ObservableList<Item> itemRow = 
                            (ObservableList<Item>) cell.getTableRow().getItem();
                    Item item = itemRow.get(columnIndex);
                    item.setDisplayColor(...);
                    item.set...(...);  
                    // ...
                    mainApp.getRLController().setItemLabel(item.toString());
                }
            });
```

Or, replace the entire row:

```
            cell.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
                Item newItem = mainApp.getTBController().getSelectedItem();
                if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY && newItem != null) {

                    ObservableList<Item> itemRow = 
                            (ObservableList<Item>) cell.getTableRow().getItem();
                    ObservableList<Item> newRow = FXCollections.observableArrayList(itemRow);
                    newRow.set(columnIndex, newItem);  
                    pattern.getItems().set(cell.getTableRow().getIndex(), newRow);
                    mainApp.getRLController().setItemLabel(newRow.get(columnIndex).toString());
                }
            });
```

Otherwise, you could make your table a `TableView<ObservableList<ObjectProperty<Item>>>`. This gets a little tricky but it's not too bad. This way you can just set the value of the object property to your new item.

Here's a complete example using the third technique:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ColorTableExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<ObservableList<ObjectProperty<Item>>> table = new TableView<>();


        int NUM_ROWS = 20 ;
        int NUM_COLS = 15 ;

        ObservableList<ObservableList<ObjectProperty<Item>>> data = table.getItems() ;

        for (int y = 0 ; y < NUM_ROWS; y++) {

            ObservableList<ObjectProperty<Item>> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            data.add(row);

            double saturation = (1.0 * y) / NUM_ROWS ;
            for (int x = 0 ; x < NUM_COLS; x++) {
                double hue = x * 360.0 / NUM_COLS ;

                Color color = Color.hsb(hue, saturation, 1.0);
                row.add(new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new Item(color)));
            }

        }

        for (ObservableList<ObjectProperty<Item>> row : table.getItems()) {
            for (int i = table.getColumns().size() ; i < row.size(); i++) {
                int columnIndex = i ;
                TableColumn<ObservableList<ObjectProperty<Item>>, Item> column = new TableColumn<>(Integer.toString(i+1));
                column.setCellValueFactory(rowData -> rowData.getValue().get(columnIndex));
                column.setCellFactory(c -> {
                    TableCell<ObservableList<ObjectProperty<Item>>, Item> cell = new TableCell<ObservableList<ObjectProperty<Item>>, Item>() {
                        @Override
                        public void updateItem(Item item, boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            if (empty) {
                                setStyle("");
                            } else {
                                Color color = item.getDisplayColor() ;
                                int r = (int) (color.getRed() * 255) ;
                                int g = (int) (color.getGreen() * 255) ;
                                int b = (int) (color.getBlue() * 255) ;
                                String style = String.format(
                                        "-fx-background-color: rgb(%d, %d, %d);"
                                        + "-fx-border-color: black ;"
                                        + "-fx-table-cell-border-color: black ;"
                                        ,r, g, b);
                                setStyle(style);
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    cell.setOnMousePressed(evt -> {
                        if (! cell.isEmpty()) {
                            ObservableList<ObjectProperty<Item>> rowData = (ObservableList<ObjectProperty<Item>>) cell.getTableRow().getItem();
                            Color currentColor = cell.getItem().getDisplayColor();
                            double newHue = ( currentColor.getHue() + 15 ) % 360 ;
                            Color newColor = Color.hsb(newHue, currentColor.getSaturation(), currentColor.getBrightness());
                            rowData.get(columnIndex).set(new Item(newColor));
                        }
                    });

                    return cell ;
                });
                table.getColumns().add(column);
            }
        }

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table, null, null, null, null);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final ObjectProperty<Color> displayColor = new SimpleObjectProperty<>() ;

        public Item(Color color) {
            this.displayColorProperty().set(color);
        }

        public final ObjectProperty<Color> displayColorProperty() {
            return this.displayColor;
        }

        public final javafx.scene.paint.Color getDisplayColor() {
            return this.displayColorProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setDisplayColor(final javafx.scene.paint.Color displayColor) {
            this.displayColorProperty().set(displayColor);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

(At some point, it might be easier to refactor everything so that you have an actual class representing each row in the table, instead of using a list.)

There may also be a clever workaround using an extractor for the list, but I couldn't make that work.

Comment: Due to the nature of the data, modifying the object isn't an option. Your second technique worked beautifully. Thank you.